# Xcode 6 build failing with missing Info.plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've got a project that I've been working on for a number of years, and everything was going really well making some changes this afternoon, until…

Xcode has stopped compiling the application. It's an ObjC application for the iPad. I get a `Shell Script Invocation Error`:

```
Source is /Users/andrew/Developer/SalesIQ/SalesIQ/SalesIQ/SalesIQ-Info.plist
Build is /Users/andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesIQ-cflsbctuolgqvpbqmuzvrkuopvkl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SalesIQ.app/Info.plist
missing file /Users/andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalesIQ-cflsbctuolgqvpbqmuzvrkuopvkl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SalesIQ.app/Info.plist
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I've even tried checking out an earlier version of the application and I still get the same error, which confuses me.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Edit: I should note that I've done a clean and build. I've rebooted. I've tried Xcode 6.0 and the 6.1 beta, and no matter what I do this error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The missing file warning is misleading. For some unknown reason, a custom script that was run during the build was failing. I deleted the `Run Script` task, then added it back in, and it's all good.

Weird…